# Play framework - securesocial - Could not find an appropriate constructor to instantiate plugin

Tags: java, playframework, securesocial, playframework-2.3

Using Play 2.3.1, Java, Scala 2.10.0

I am trying to integrate **securesocial** in my web project

**/build.sbt**

> lazy val root = project.in( file(".") ).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
>       scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
>
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   jdbc,   cache,   filters,   anorm,
>   "com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-util" % "2.3.0",
>   "com.typesafe.play.plugins" %% "play-plugins-mailer" % "2.3.0",
>   "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",   "ws.securesocial" %%
>   "securesocial" % "**master-SNAPSHOT**" )
>
> resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

**conf/play.plugins**

> 1500:com.typesafe.plugin.CommonsMailerPlugin
>   10001:securesocial.core.providers.FacebookProvider

**conf/securesocial.conf**

```
securesocial {
    onLoginGoTo=/
    onLogoutGoTo=/login
    ssl=false   
    assetsController=controllers.ReverseMyCustomAssetsController

    userpass {      
        withUserNameSupport=false
        sendWelcomeEmail=true
        enableGravatarSupport=true
        signupSkipLogin=true
        tokenDuration=60
        tokenDeleteInterval=5
        minimumPasswordLength=8
        enableTokenJob=true
        hasher=bcrypt
    }
    twitter {
        requestTokenUrl="https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
        accessTokenUrl="https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
        authorizationUrl="https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate"
        consumerKey=your_consumer_key
        consumerSecret=your_consumer_secret
    }

    facebook {
        authorizationUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize"
        accessTokenUrl="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"
        clientId=your_client_id
        clientSecret=your_client_secret
        # this scope is the minimum SecureSocial requires.  You can add more if required by your app.
        scope=email
    }

    google {
        authorizationUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
        accessTokenUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
        clientId=your_client_id
        clientSecret=your_client_secret
        scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    }
}
```

But getting below error

> Could not find an appropriate constructor to instantiate plugin
>   [securesocial.core.providers.FacebookProvider]. All Play plugins must
>   define a constructor that accepts a single argument either of type
>   play.Application for Java plugins or play.api.Application for Scala
>   plugins.

The project compiled successfully.

What I am missing? Any pointer will be useful on how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the latest refactorings in master the module does not use plugins any more. All the things you specified using plugins have now to be defined in a RuntimeEnvironment.

Check out the sample apps to see how it is used.